# Xamarin Forms - Saving Picture By Sending it to the Servers

Tags: xamarin.forms

So I was able to get the camera function from xamarin forms labs to work and save the picture in a file. But now I want to send this image saved as a jpg to my server as a byte array. How would I be able to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to convert the image on the mobile device to a byte array. For example, on iOS you can use this extension method

```
    public static byte[] ToByteArray(this UIImage image)
    {
        if (image == null)
            return null;

        using (image)
        {
            using (var data = image.AsJPEG())
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[data.Length];
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data.Bytes, bytes, 0, (int)data.Length);
                return bytes;
            }
        }
    }
```

Once you have the byte array, then you just need to HTTP POST it back to your server.